# "Glistening from" vs "Glistening with"

Tags: word-choice, grammar, prepositions

Consider the following sentence:

> The metal sheets are glistening with water drops filled with a mix of dust and acid."

It is unclear to me if I can rewrite it using "glistening from":

> "The metal sheets are glistening from water drops filled with a mix of dust and acid."

The only dictionary example I could find states "glistening *with* sweat" rather than "glistening *from* sweat", but it doesn't explain why.

> "Gone are the wavy curls, glistening with sweat and flopping a full
>   second behind his every move."

(*The Daily Beast,* "Roger Federer’s Hair Evolution", by Sujay Kumar, June 8, 2013, given as an example by [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/glistening))

Comment: Maybe this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=glistening+*+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cglistening%20%2A%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bglistening%20in%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bglistening%20on%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bglistening%20with%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bglistening%20of%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bglistening%20through%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bglistening%20under%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bglistening%20from%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bglistening%20among%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bglistening%20at%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bglistening%20upon%20the%3B%2Cc0) will be of interest.

Comment: Thank you @Jim. I modified yours, into one that [poignantly shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=glistening+from%2Cglistening+with%2C+glistening+in&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=40&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cglistening%20from%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cglistening%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cglistening%20in%3B%2Cc0) how glistening from is almost never used.

Comment: @BennyBottema - But it ***is*** used.  As George Carlin points out, [“Hand me that piano”](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hand+me+that+knife%2C+hand+me+that+piano&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chand%20me%20that%20knife%3B%2Cc0) is also hardly ever used, but it’s perfectly grammatical.

Comment: ngram [glistening from *](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=glistening+from+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cglistening%20from%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bglistening%20from%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bglistening%20from%20under%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bglistening%20from%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bglistening%20from%20their%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bglistening%20from%20her%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bglistening%20from%20his%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bglistening%20from%20its%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bglistening%20from%20every%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bglistening%20from%20head%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bglistening%20from%20trucks%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Then do “glistening from the *”  the link is too long to post in a comment.

Comment: An example of '*glistening from*' would be "his hair still glistening from the shower" (google `"glistening from"` **with** the `"`s, and it will search for that exact phrase. Some of them are ungrammatical, but it does find some kosher examples)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **with** or **from** should be make a difference in the meaning of the adverbial adjunct.

Glistening **with**:

> A shrub glistening **with** ice ([see reference](http://www.yourdictionary.com/glisten))

The ice is the **medium** through which the glistening happens.

The usage with *from* does not seem that usual; I would use it to describe the **source** of the glistening: light (or some causal event).

> The diamond was glistening **from** the lights in the ceiling.
>
> He was dressed neatly in grey flannel trousers, jacket and blue striped shirt, his hair still glistening **from** the shower ([see reference](http://sentencedict.com/glistening.html), no 30).

For your question, the sentence:

> The metal sheets are glistening **with** water drops filled with a mix of water and acid.

I guess they are glistening **from** the sun.

Comment: Have you any idea which corpus/corpora Sentencedict.com draws from, fralau?

Comment: No, unfortunately I don't know. I used it because it made sense.

Comment: To glisten from [x] provides the source or result that produces the glistening. /To glisten with/ goes to the substance of the glistening. Glistening from exerting effort. Glistening with anticipation.

Comment: 'Sentencedict' could be a very valuable source, but some endorsement of its reliability is needed.

Answer (score 0):

glistening with an object = the thing that is glistening is stated.
glistening from [some activity]= goes to what causes the glistening.

1) Her face **glistened with raindrops** = an object, raindrops make her face glisten.

2) Her face **glistened from overexertion**. An activity

the implication is here: there are drops of sweat on her face.

In my view, this is basically the answer to the with/from "conundrum".

reference: my head